# 13.10 Support Cycle

Tags: 13.10

I am running 12.04 LTS and want to upgrade to 13.10.
When does the 9 month support cycle end?
What happens to 13.10 when it ends?
Does the Update manager upgrade you to the next version / release when available and before the cycle ends for 13.10?

Comment: you should read this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases 13.10 has end of support in jully and *14* . *04* will be realease in  20 *14* / *04* so yes you will be able to upgrade using version full upgrade.

Comment: I would propose you hang on to your 12.04LTS release and upgrade in April directly to 14.04LTS when it's released. It's just one more month.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 13.10 will be supported until July 2014. Here's a graph that shows support cycles for every ubuntu versions:

[image]